# Angular 4 jasmine spy function

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a relatively simple component, but cannot manage to get a spy successfully registering calls.
The calls are definitely happening as expected, as I've hacked my own version of a spy, but the jasmine Spy does not appear to be working as expected.
I expect it's something to do with the asynchronicity, as I definitely don't understand how that all works within the test framework, and have just cobbled together bits form examples.

In the below example, the current test is passing, but the final log output shows that the spy has not detected any calls.

If it's not obvious from the code, this component consists of a simple login page. There are two input fields (email and password) and a login button, which triggers the component's login() function, triggering the (mocked here) user service's login function with the value in the email field (password is currently not used)

```
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MessengerService } from '../messenger/messenger.service';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';

describe('Login Component', () => {
    let comp: LoginComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
    let mockMessengerService: any = { 
    };  
    let mockUserService: any = { 
        login: (username: string) => {
            console.log('in function');
            calledWith = username;
            return;
        },  
    };  
    let calledWith: string;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                NoopAnimationsModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                FormsModule,
                MaterialModule,
            ],  
            declarations: [
                LoginComponent,
            ],  
            providers: [
                {   
                    provide: MessengerService,
                    useValue: mockMessengerService,
                },  
                {   
                    provide: UserService,
                    useValue: mockUserService,
                },
            ],
        })
        .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        calledWith = undefined;
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should call user.login with email as parameter', async(() => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            const emailDe: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#email'));
            const emailEl: HTMLInputElement = emailDe.nativeElement;

            let loginSpy = spyOn(mockUserService, 'login');

            emailEl.value = 'test@test.com';
            emailEl.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
            fixture.detectChanges();

            comp.login();
            expect(calledWith).toBe('test@test.com');
            console.log('spyCalled: ' + loginSpy.calls.any());
        });
    }));
});
```

I'm currently hoping that I've just missed a simple piece of information and it will be obvious to somebody with more experience than me, but if that doesn't happen, I'll look into creating a minimal example showing the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if its relevant, but my app is bundled through webpack, and the test is run via karma, as per angular's own guide on using webpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got it working, it looks like the issue is that I should have been spying on the function on the injected provider, instead of the mocked prototype (or something along those lines, I'd be lying if I said I understood...)

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         imports: [   
             NoopAnimationsModule,           
             RouterTestingModule,            
             FormsModule,
             MatCardModule,
             MatButtonModule,                
             MatInputModule,
         ],           
         declarations: [ 
            LoginComponent,
         ],
         providers: [
             {        
                 provide: MessengerService,      
                 useValue: mockMessengerService, 
             },       
             {        
                 provide: UserService,           
                 useValue: mockUserService,      
             },       
         ],
     })
     .compileComponents();

     fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
     comp = fixture.componentInstance;

     debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
     loginService = debugElement.injector.get(UserService);
     loginSpy = spyOn(loginService, 'login');
}));
```